# How to build a smart wall

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor

I want to build a smart wall where people can touch a 2 sqft region of the wall and it will detect who touched it and which cell they touched. The wall itself is made of plywood and I have access to both sides. You can think of it like turning the wall into a giant board game, where I have some server behind the wall and when it's a player's turn, they tap a couple of areas to move their game piece. The resulting move is displayed on their mobile phone, so it does not need to be displayed anywhere on the wall.

Given my requirements:

- ~50cm omnidirectional proximity detection
- Ideally I can place it on the back of the wall, rather than in front. I only have control of the wall itself, setting up additional sensors elsewhere in the room is not feasible.
- Uniquely identify each player for stats tracking. Players can wear some sort of bracelet if it helps the sensor, but it should not be much heavier than a LiveStrong bracelet; the hands must remain totally free.
- As cheap as possible. My budget is < $30 per 2 sqft cell.

How can I build this smart wall?

Comment: What on earth is wrong with you people? This question is entirely clear and is well "bounded". I don't know what most of the closers don't know, but I do know that Olin could happily answer this and I'd be stunned if he genuinely could not understand it well enough to do so. *OR* What am I missing?

Comment: Thank you! I keep getting my questions around this closed. As a follow up to this, I asked where I can find an RFID reader that meets the above requirements, and they closed it as a dupe of this question. Really frustrating!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RFID Bracelets, with readers behind the tile, assuming they are 2 sqft each. Connected to a bluetooth or web enabled microcontroller (or an arduino or similar) or computer to handle all the backend and display updating.